# Casting &i32 as usize

Tags: rust

I have a function that is meant to make a move in connect 4, this function takes 3 parameters. The main issue is that the square variable is out of scope in the for loop so it must be borrowed however I cannot cast an `&i32` to `usize`.

```rust
fn make_move<'playing>(board: &'playing Vec<&str>, column: i32, turn: &'playing i32) -> &'playing Vec<&'playing str> {
    let mut square = column;
    let new_board = board;

    for i in 0..6 {
        if new_board[(&square) as usize] == " " {
            square = &square + 7;
        } else {
            if turn % 2 == 0 {
                new_board[(&square - 7) as usize] = "●";
            } else {
                new_board[(&square - 7) as usize] = "○";
            }
        }
    }
    return new_board;
}
```

```
error[E0606]: casting `&i32` as `usize` is invalid
 --> src/lib.rs:6:22
  |
6 |         if new_board[(&square) as usize] == " " {
  |                      ---------^^^^^^^^^
  |                      |
  |                      cannot cast `&i32` as `usize`
  |                      help: dereference the expression: `*(&square)`
```

I also just started using Rust so I am sure my logic is flawed and maybe this is a dumb mistake but help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't need the ampersands at all before `square`.  `square` is an `i32`, which is an integer type, and you want to turn it into another integer type, so you don't need to borrow it at all.  Since `i32` is `Copy`, you can make cheap copies of `square` without a problem.

Additionally, `new_board` is making a copy of your reference to `board`, not copying the actual board.  `Vec` is not `Copy`, since copies are not cheap, so you'll need to use the `clone` method to create a new board and then return the actual `Vec`, not a reference.  With the above change and this one, the result would look like this:

```
fn make_move<'playing>(
    board: &'playing Vec<&str>,
    column: i32,
    turn: &'playing i32,
) -> Vec<&'playing str> {
    let mut square = column;
    let mut new_board = board.clone();

    for i in 0..6 {
        if new_board[(square) as usize] == " " {
            square = square + 7;
        } else {
            if turn % 2 == 0 {
                new_board[(square - 7) as usize] = "●";
            } else {
                new_board[(square - 7) as usize] = "○";
            }
        }
    }
    return new_board;
}
```

Alternatively, you can make `board` a mutable reference, in which case you will modify both the old and new board, but you can continue to return a reference.  That would look like this:

```
fn make_move<'playing>(
    board: &'playing mut Vec<&str>,
    column: i32,
    turn: &'playing i32,
) -> &'playing Vec<&'playing str> {
    let mut square = column;
    let new_board = board;

    for i in 0..6 {
        if new_board[(square) as usize] == " " {
            square = square + 7;
        } else {
            if turn % 2 == 0 {
                new_board[(square - 7) as usize] = "●";
            } else {
                new_board[(square - 7) as usize] = "○";
            }
        }
    }
    return new_board;
}
```

Comment: I cannot just make copies inside the for loop because that uses a moved value.

Comment: You can absolutely make copies of `square`, since it's an `i32`. I've provided some examples to demonstrate what I'm talking about.